# Unmarshalling unknown type code exception while resuming

Tags: android, unmarshalling, parcelable

I have an application in which i got tablayout with two fragments, the app works perfectly fine but when i close app using menu button and use other apps for a while and when i resume my app it crashes with the following exception

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.com, PID: 5674
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.com/com.example.ui.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@9095b3a: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3801188 at offset 4392
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@9095b3a: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3801188 at offset 4392
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2340)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
>                                                                                  at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:856)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2033)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1008)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:963)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1186)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

i tried disabling the proguard  and adding below code but nothing helps

> -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>       static ** CREATOR;
>   }

i have custom view but haven't implemented parcelable in them also i have striped everything from fragment and just kept the view even then it  was crashing but when i was just loading instance of fragment like 
new android.support.v4.app.Fragment(); i wasn't getting the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parcel Unmarshalling unknown type code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672772/parcel-unmarshalling-unknown-type-code)

Comment: As i tried to figure out the issue, i saw that when i remove the android.support.v7.widget.SearchView from my option menu  code of the fragment didn't crashed, this might be the possible issue but didnt know why its happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue and found the solution to start the app again to stop the crash
In your MainActivity
Use:

```
    @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx for help the solution worked, but still i cant understand why its happening when i used searchview in android

Comment: @Ankit Singh: Accept the answer if it has helped to solved you problem

Comment: This is more of a workaround really, but it does work. I have the exact same problem with a searchview, really strange stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This was due to a [bug in SearchView](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201836) since appcompat v23.2.0.

It is fixed in v23.2.1. Upgrade your support libraries to get rid of the exception.